# Transaction propagation in spring @required

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, java-11

```
@GetMapping("trans")
    @Transactional()
    public String primaryTrans() {
        User u1 = new User(0,"test","test@email.com");
        us.save(u1);
        User u2 = new User(0,"test1","test1@email.com");
        us.save(u2);
        secondaryTrans();
        return "index";
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    private void secondaryTrans() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        User u2 = new User(0,"test2","test3@email.com".repeat(300));
        us.save(u2);
    }
```

Here i am manually raising DATA TOO LONG exception from secondary transaction, But it causes primary transaction also rolled back. How can we make sure that primary transaction to be committed irrespective of secondary transaction

Comment: There is no second transaction... The `@Transactional` on a `private` method is useless and even if the method was `public` it would be useless. Spring AOP works with proxies (only `public` and `protected` methods can be proxied) and internal method calls don't pass through the proxy (hence making them `public` is useless as well). To make it work either move the method to a seperate class and call it or configure full blown aspectj with load or compile time weaving. Finally making your controller transactional is also a bad idea... Move that to a service instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, since the second method is called from the same class, the second transaction is most likely not created. Springs transactional support uses AOP proxies to create transactions. The docs contain a [description on why this will not work](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies).

Comment: Thanks for the link as well, it solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to catch the exception thrown from `secondaryTrans()` method, so just wrap `secondaryTrans()` into try-catch block:

```java
try {
  secondaryTrans();
} catch (Exception e) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: i tried it , nothing is saving in the DB

Comment: Is the data saved into your DB if you comment out `secondaryTrans()`?

Comment: Yes , if i comment secondaryTrans()  two rows are inserting without any issue